# How can I fix Debian "Problem loading UEFI:db X.509 certificate (-65)" error message!

Tags: debian, dmesg

Debian 10 on an Acer Aspire A515-51G, UEFI boot

---

I have this error displayed at boot logs and in "dmesg".

Other threads I have found, suggested to disable "Secure Boot" in BIOS but that didn't fix the error. I think that most of the threads are for previous versions of Debian from which, user were unable to boot at all.

[image]

Comment: Issues often common by brand. May be similar? Acer Aspire 7 A715-71G NVE not seen Boot parameter: nvme_core.default_ps_max_latency_us=200 
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2429323
Acer Aspire A315-53-386P remove RAID from drive
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1167506/the-installation-window-dont-show-a-root-file-system-for-choose-in-the-installa

Comment: does issues doesn't seem to be related

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acer laptops have two obsolete certificates which cause this error.

You may patch the kernel with : https://lkml.org/lkml/2019/3/22/60 , or just ignore it since it is too much of a hassle. I don't know of any other way. Perhaps there must be a way of removing those certificates.

Tbh it's very ugly since it comes between grub and plymouth.